# What is best way to add static blocks in front-end without defining css for responsiveness?

Tags: magento2, layout, css

I want to define some static blocks in the header and footer of my theme
but I don't want to define css for their responsiveness.

**Can I define static blocks, managed by magento admin panel for my front-end theme
without damaging responsiveness of theme template?**

This is my header

[image]

here i have add this static block (Get 30-40% off on over 1,50,00 style).
I want to edit this block by admin panel without defining responsive css.

Comment: Design depends on kind of content you are giving in static block.So the need of css. Can you share more info.

Comment: need to define simple blocks like these..do i need to define css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static blocks have nothing to do with CSS or responsiveness, all they do is render the contents of the respective static block.

To load a static block you have a few options:

#### Via XML

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer.links.block" as="footerLinksBlock">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_identifier</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

#### Via Template

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

#### Via CMS page or another static block

```
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}
```

Comment: but content of the newly defined block don't adjust according to screen size
(mobile view, desktop view)

Comment: Nope, you need to write your own CSS for that. Static blocks do not have any responsive functionality, it literally renders whatever you add to your static block.